# ¿Cómo obtener el ID del último INSERT?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

La idea es sencilla, cuando acabo de insertar una nueva fila a mi tabla **ventas**, requiero obtener el `id` de la fila insertada.

Por lo pronto tengo esta funcion que retorna un `bool`, lo que deseo es cambiarlo a un `int`  este sea el **id de la fila insertada**:

```
internal static String table = "ventas";
//cambiare el valor de retorno por un int.
public static bool Insertar(MVentas objeto, facturacion.Vistas.VVentas form)
{

    MySqlConnection SqlCon = new MySqlConnection(Conexion.Cn);
    try
    {
        SqlCon.Open();
        string query001 = "INSERT INTO " + table + "(idCliente,idUsuario,fecVenta,montoTotal,montoLiteral,tipo,estado) Values(@idCliente,@idUsuario,@fecVenta,@montoTotal,@montoLiteral,@tipo,@estado)";
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query001, SqlCon);
        MessageBoxEx.Show(objeto.idUsuario.ToString());
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idCliente", objeto.idCliente);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idUsuario", objeto.idUsuario);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecVenta", objeto.fecVenta);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@montoTotal", objeto.montoTotal);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@montoLiteral", objeto.montoLiteral);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo", objeto.tipo);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estado", objeto.estado);


        if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
        {
            ToastNotification.Show(form, "venta Creada Correctamente", global::facturacion.Properties.Resources.ok, 3000, (eToastGlowColor.Green), (eToastPosition.TopRight));
            SqlCon.Close();
            return true;// aqui en cambio de true retornar el id;
        }
        else
        {
            ToastNotification.Show(form, "La venta no pudo ser Creada", global::facturacion.Properties.Resources.error, 3000, (eToastGlowColor.Red), (eToastPosition.TopRight));
            SqlCon.Close();
            return false;//aqui algo como -1
        }
    }
    catch (MySqlException e)
    {
        ToastNotification.Show(form, e.Message, global::facturacion.Properties.Resources.error, 3000, (eToastGlowColor.Red), (eToastPosition.TopLeft));
        return false;//aqui algo como -1
    }
}
```

Por ahora estoy haciendo **otra consulta**(un proceso similar a este) que me retorna la ultima fila, pero creo que es un mal procedimiento, ya que el sistema es para la venta de productos y tiene como 6 ventanillas de cancelacion continua, y me preocupa que el proceso que tengo ahora cause conflictos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existe un metodo para regresar el ultimo id insertado:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as lastid
```

Esta consulta retornará el último ID, la puedes ejecutar despues del `INSERT`. No importa si alguien hace alguna otra inserción al mismo tiempo ya que esta consulta respeta las sesiones y obtiene el ultimo ID que tú insertaste.

Toda la información al respecto [aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: @ReneLimon, lo implemento y te aviso como me va ok.

Comment: Cabe mencionar que para que esto funcione tu id deberá ser auto_increment de lo contrario siempre vas a recibir un "0" como resultado

Comment: en C#, utilice la funcion `LastInsertedId` asi: `id=command.LastInsertedId;` y retorne el id, me ayudo mucho tu respuesta.

Comment: No me consta, pero supongo que ese método justo ejecuta esta consulta. Me alegra haber sido de ayuda